# Is it possible to import csv file in solr with .jsp web page?

Tags: jsp, solr

Is there any method to import **.csv** file in solr's cores with any web page? If there is it, how we do it? I don't have any idea how I do it? Help pls :)

Comment: Have you seen [CSV Formatted Index Updates](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#csv-formatted-index-updates)?

Comment: Yes. Is there any tutorial for this? It'll help me understand it better.

Comment: There's an literal example on how to do it as the first example - have you tried that? `curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/my_collection/update?commit=true' --data-binary @example/exampledocs/books.csv -H 'Content-type:application/csv'`